# What values can rank(A) and rank(A^2) have?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Determine the set of ordered pairs {$(rank(A),rank(A^2)) : A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}$)}

My prof gave the hint that we can use Sylvester's rank inequality: if A is an m × n matrix and B is n × k, then $Rank(A) + Rank(B) - n \leq Rank(AB)$.

I have found the inequalities $rank(A) \geq rank(A^2)$ and $rank(A) \leq (Rank(A^2) + n)/2$. Letting $A^2 = 0$ we get that $rank(A) \leq n/2$. I'm not sure how this upper bound helps me.
The pairs (0,0), (1,1) ..., (n,n) can all be found when $A^2 = A.$ My intuition tells me that the answer should be $\{(a,b) : a,b \leq n$ and $a,b \geq 0\}$ but I have no clue how to prove that. Any ideas?

Comment: You guess that any pair $(a,b)$ with $a,b\geq0$ and $a,b\leq n$ is a solution? But you already said that $rank(A) \geq rank(A^2)$, which gives $a\geq b$. So you already know that your guess isn't correct.

Comment: Each application of $A$ can reduce dimensionality by at most $n-rank(A)$, which is the dimension of its nullspace. The least it can reduce it by is $0$, i.e., it will never increase dimensionality. So, for a given rank $r$, can you *construct* matrices $A_k$ for $k=r-(n-r)..r$ where $rank(A_k)=r$ and $rank(A_k^2)=k$? (Think about $A$ as the sum of an outer product and think about how orthogonality can be useful.)

Comment: For intuition, think of multiplying two diagonal matrices of rank $r$ and ask what are the possibilities. Easy ones are $r=n$ and $r=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylvester gives $\operatorname{rk} A^2 \ge 2 \operatorname{rk} A - n$ and you know that $\operatorname{rk} A^2 \le \operatorname{rk} A$.

So, you can guess that
$\max(0, 2 \operatorname{rk} A - n) \le \operatorname{rk} A^2 \le \operatorname{rk} A $, or
that $P= \{ (r,q) | \max(0,2r-n) \le q \le r \}$ is the set of pairs.

To finish we need to exhibit matrices with any value $(r,q) \in P$.

Let $\Lambda$ be a diagonal matrix with $r$ ones in the $(1,1),...,(r,r)$ positions and let $S $ be a 'right rotation', that is $S e_k = e_{k+1}, S e_n = e_1$. Then let $A = \Lambda S^{r-q}$ and note that $\operatorname{rk} = r$.

Note that $\Lambda e_k = \begin{cases} e_k, & k \le r \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$,
$\ \ S^{r-q}\Lambda e_k = \begin{cases} e_{k+r-q}, & k \le r \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ and so
$\Lambda S^{r-q}\Lambda e_k = \begin{cases} e_{k+r-q}, & k \le q \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Noting that $A^2 = S^{r-q} \Lambda S^{r-q}\Lambda $ it follows that $\operatorname{rk} A^2 = q$ and so $(r,q) \in P$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Do the same problem but with nullity instead of rank. That's easier and more intuitive to think and reason about. Then use the rank-nullity theorem to translate.